# Sidekiq perform_async with Apnotic (Apple Push Notifications)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications, sidekiq

I'm receiving this an error when trying to run Sidekiq workers asynchronously, which I am not receiving when the code is run on the main thread.

I'm trying to send push notifications to an iOS app, using Apnotic. This is my worker code:

```rb
class ApnWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'default'

  APNOTIC_POOL = Apnotic::ConnectionPool.new(...)

  def perform(notification) # Apnotic::Notification.new(device_token)
    APNOTIC_POOL.with do |connection|
      response = connection.push(notification)
      raise "APN Connection Timeout" unless response

      if response.status == "410" ||
        (response.status == "400" && response.body["reason"] == "BadDeviceToken")
        User.find_by(device_token: notification.token).update!(device_token: nil)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

These jobs are then failing, and ending up in my retry queue. This error is shown as the reason:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `authorization=' for "#<Apnotic::Notification:0x000055e08470a980>"
```

I searched my app and there is no use of the word `authorization` anywhere. Best guess is that Sidekiq is calling `authorization=` on the notification I'm passing them, but I'm quite confused as to why.

Any guidance would be most helpful.

**UPDATE**

I found out where the `authorization=` call is coming from, it's part of Apnotic's process of preparing the push notification:

```rb
def prepare_request(notification)
  notification.authorization = provider_token if @auth_method == :token
  Apnotic::Request.new(notification)
end
```

So my guess that Sidekiq was calling that was incorrect, but this doesn't help that much with a solution. The `Apnotic::Notification` I'm sending my worker is the same whether async or not, and they should both respond to `authorization=`, so why is the async raising an error?

Still super stuck on this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with how Sidekiq serializes your `Apnotic::Notification` object. The documentation suggests that you [don't pass complex objects as parameters to your sidekiq jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple). Instead of serializing the notification object, perhaps you can pass the device token to the job (Assuming it's just a string) and rewrite your code to something like:

```
def perform(device_token) 
  notification = Apnotic::Notification.new(device_token)
  APNOTIC_POOL.with do |connection|
    response = connection.push(notification)
    raise "APN Connection Timeout" unless response

    if response.status == "410" ||
      (response.status == "400" && response.body["reason"] == "BadDeviceToken")
      User.find_by(device_token: notification.token).update!(device_token: nil)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of device_token can you try with apns_token.

it also matters wheather you are sending notification using apns or voip service.